# Meteor iron-router not loading data

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have this basic route in place and my template does not receive the data I am setting.

```
App =
    subs:
        posts: Meteor.subscribe "posts"
        users: Meteor.subscribe "users"

Router.configure
    wait: [App.subs.posts, App.subs.users]
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'

Router.map ->
    @route 'post_show',
        path: '/p/:slug'
        before: ->
            if App.subs.post
                App.subs.post.stop()
            App.subs.post = Meteor.subscribe "post", @params.slug

        waitOn: ->
            App.subs.post

        after: ->
            if @getData().post
                document.title = @getData().post?.title

        data: ->
            p = Posts.findOne
                $or: [{
                    slug: @params.slug
                }, {
                    _id: @params.slug
                }]

            date = new Date p.timestamp
            date_added = "{0}-{1}-{2}".format date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate()

            data =
                post: p
                date_added: date_added
            data
        template: 'post_show'
```

Server code:

```
Meteor.publish "posts", ->
    return Posts.find()

Meteor.publish "post", (id_or_slug) ->
    return Posts.find({
        $or: [{
            slug: id_or_slug
        }, {
            _id: id_or_slug
        }]
    })

Meteor.publish "userData", ->
    return Meteor.users.find {},
        fields:
            profile: 1
```

When I refresh the page the `p` variable inside the `data` method is undefined. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two publications ("posts", and "post") on the same back-end collection ("posts"). As far as I know that's not possible, because the client-side collection needs to match the collection name on the server side. The name under which you publish it doesn't matter so much.

This is also explained in the "counts-by-room" example of http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish.

This raises the question why you would first publish all the posts and then, in addition, publish a subset of that. Can't you just do that subsetting on the client then?

Comment: I agree with that I was asking myself the same question. Was just following this tut: https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/q8QWX5e7PTu8BEReY (check minute 12)

Comment: You can have multiple publish functions for the same collection. In fact you should in most cases as you don't need the entire collection published just to view one post. If you think the problem is in the publish function, run Posts.find().fetch() in your console and see what it returns... If you are getting output from that the problem is in the route. :)

Comment: I followed your advice and saw a strange thing. If I update a post and call `Posts.find().fetch()` it returns my posts but the one I edited still contains the old data (without my edits). If I check the mongodb database the changes are submitted so my client does not update for some reason and that's why I can't redirect to the new slug because my client still holds the old data. I removed the publish code and I just subscribe to `posts` now but still without any luck regarding this matter.